# How do the apps Flora and Forest know when you access another app in the background? [Swift]

Tags: swift

I am creating a similar pomodoro style app where I want to punish the user when they go on another app. I am wondering how apps like forest or flora detect when you access another app when they're in the background.

Comment: How is this question lacking focus? It's a singular, simple, question. How can an app detect when other apps are brought to the foreground?

Comment: iOS Apps running are declared as private and you will not have permission to which app is currently foregrounded. Only the OS Apps would serve that API. Check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1534059-runningapplications

Also as an advice, your pomodoro app would check when app goes background and "punish" user.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to make the app punish the user when it goes to the background but it cannot differentiate between the user leaving the app or the phone turning off.